# Understanding function type

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

`std::function<int(float)>`: in here `int(float)` is a function type that returns an `int` and accepts (as an argument) `float`.

What I'm trying to understand

- `std::function<int(float) const>`
- `std::function<int(float) const&>`

What is the meaning of the `const` and `const&` in the above statements

Thank you

Comment: Is that valid?  Fascinating!  I think the first refers to a function that doesn't modify the function(oid), but I'm struggling to understand the latter one.

Comment: @MooingDuck It's not valid. Per C++17 [func.wrap.func] the template `std::function<T>` is only defined when `T` is of the form `R(ArgTypes...)`

Comment: That's a little sad. That means you can't guarantee a reseatable `std::function<...>` to a non-mutable functionoid.